# How to copy row using a checkbox from one tab and add it to the bottom of the tab and two additional tabs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are several StackOverflow questions that address moving a row of data to an outside sheet and within a sheet. What I'd like to do is unite these within the same sheet but I've had issues with the script working `onEdit` and writing to the same tab and two additional tabs within the same sheet using a loop.

If the checkbox in the "test1" tab is selected, duplicate the row at the bottom of tabs "test1", "test2", and "completed"

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_wHyVcR-rCBP6doJEQFqjwCdD6gzXsk_eU8p8MusmvY/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sec = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //  var s = ss.getSheetByName("test1");
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  // Duplicates an order as a new draft on the last row of the draft tab
  if (s.getName() == "test1" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

    //var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("draft");

    var sheets = ['test1', 'test2', 'Completed']
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var sheetName = sheets[i]
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      if (sheet != null) {
        targetsheet(sheet)

      }
    }


    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
      targetsheet(sheet)
    })

    var target = sheets.getRange(sheets.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.copyRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this line `targetsheet(sheet)` supposed to do?

Comment: You should specify which issues do you have *exactly*, this way the question will be useful to other users as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry')
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const sA=['Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4'];//tabs to copy to
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==9 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Conditional');
    const row=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    sA.forEach(function(name){
      let sh=e.source.getSheetByName(name);
      sh.appendRow(row);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cooper for taking the time to review. You reference 'Entry' and 'Conditional' in the script above. If the checkbox on test1 tab is driving the replication/copy do I change 'Entry' and 'Conditional' to 'test1'?

Comment: Entry and conditional are just toasts used for debugging purposes I would just comment them out but you can do whatever you wish.